# How to go through list of arrays, and merge pairs based on mutual information calculation in python

Tags: python, networkx

I currently have a list of arrays that represent cell counts from different samples, and each array represents a different grouping. I have this structured as a networkx graph (for other purposes), whereby node name is the grouping, and the node attribute is the cell counts.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Calculate mutual information (MI) for all possible pairings of arrays/nodes
2. Sort these pairings, and find the greatest MI value that is also above a given threshold.
3. Merge the counts for the pair via summing values and creating a new node while deleting the original.
4. Repeat from step one where now there is one less node as two have been merged, until there is no longer a MI that is above the threshold.

Right now I can get up until step 3, but I don't know how I would go about repeating this process efficiently?

Here is what I have so far:

```
def optimize_MI(G, binsize, threshold):
    ''' 
    1. sort edges with highest MI
    2. merge nodes with highest MI if MI>threshold
    3. Create new node, delete original two
    4. Repeat
    '''
    #find children with no predecessors (backwards)
    finest = []
    for node in G.nodes():
        if len(G.predecessors(node)) == 0:
            finest.append(node)
    #calculate MI for all pairs and sort
    edges = []
    for x in finest:
        for y in finest:
            if G.successors(x) == G.successors(y):
                mi = calc_MI(G.node[x]['count'], G.node[y]['count'], binsize)                
                edge = (x, y, {'MI': mi})
                edges.append(edge)
    edges_sorted = sorted(edges, key=lambda score: score[2]['MI'])
    #make new node
    pair = edges_sorted[-1]    
    if pair[2]['MI'] > threshold:
        count = G.node[pair[0]] + G.node[pair[1]])
        node_name = pair[0] + ' + ' + pair[1]
        G.add_node(node_name, counts=count)
        G.remove_nodes_from([pair[0], pair[1]])
        G.add_edge(node_name, G.successors(pair[0]))
```

Thanks for any advice you may have!